# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\pi k)}{\sqrt{2 k} \log (2 k)}$: absolute convergent, conditional convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I will like to determine whether the following series $$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\pi k)}{\sqrt{2 k} \log (2 k)}
$$ is absolute convergent, conditional convergent or divergent. I have been looking in my textbooks for some results to use. But I can't find anything which I can use directly. So I think I have to do a bit more groundwork. The first think I thought about was to split the sum into a positive sum and a negative sum.  If these two sub sums diverges, then the sum is absolute convergent. What do you guys think about my thinking?

Another problem is that I actually do not know how to split the sum in a negative sum and a positive sum.

Comment: *Hint:* $\sqrt n\log n< n$ for $n\gg 0$. Also, Leibniz

Comment: This is a general sum, so I can't use Leibniz.

Comment: Think of Dirichlet's test.(Abel's rule).

Comment: @Xenusi, you have totally vandalised your own post! It is now unreadable.

Comment: Ups! I will get it fixed. I download I spell checker and tried to do something smart with it. Obviously, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(\pi n/2)$ is $0$ if $n$ is odd. So, your sum can be restricted to even numbers. Let's use $n=2k$, so that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\sqrt{2k}\log (2k)}$$
Note that $\cos(\pi k)=(-1)^k$, so your sum is actually an alternating series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{2k}\log (2k)}$$
Look for "alternating series test" to check that this is a convergent series.

Now, this series is not absolutely convergent since $\left|\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{2k}\log (2k)}\right|\gg\frac{1}{k}$ (and the harmonic series diverges).

Comment: Which fundamental inequality have you used?

Comment: @Xenusi what do you mean?

Comment: How can one derive this $$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 k} \log (2 k)} \gg \frac{1}{k}
$$ holdes. I can see intuitively that it holdes for sufficient big $k$. So $k >> 1$